# Checking availability of address when binding in ZMQJS

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I'm working with an automated system written in nodeJS that creates on the fly nodes across the cloud connecting them by the means of the ZMQ binding for nodeJS. Sometimes I get the error `Error: Address already in use`, which is my bad because I have some bug somewhere. I would like to know if it's possible with the nodeJS binding of ZMQ to check the availability of the address before binding it.

Comment: Socket.{bind,bindSync}() does the test by failing when it's occupied, what is the problem? I mean how do you want it to work? You know that it is no good when you get an exception...

Comment: Yes I know, and I also know that in theory with a try-catch I can catch the error, my point is that I want to avoid the error at all by performing a sort of check on the port. I would like to know if this is possible or I should go with the try-catch option.

Comment: I would say that there is no other reliable way, because otherwise you can check it, some other process binds your port, you try to bind and you fail. So it does not bring any benefit, just one more unnecessary check.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see the thing under the "race condition" point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really what I was searching for, but in the end I decided to go for the "simple" solution and use a `try-catch` block to check if there is an error when binding to a `host:port`. In practice this is what I do:

```
try {
    receiver.bindSync("tcp://"+host+":" + port);
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Which is stupid and straight forward. I was looking for a more accurate way to do this (for example, as mentioned in the question, a function to check the availability of the address, rather than catching the error).